# How to Run Dredge Function in Parallel

Tags: r, mumin

I have been trying to run the dredge function on one of my models, however I would like to run the dredge function in parallel to save time considering that I have ~20 variables in my model. So far I'm running into an error in my attempts to run the dredge function in parallel

Here's a working example using data from the palmerpenguins package

```
library(palmerpenguins)
library(MuMIn)

#create and clean the dataframe
penguin<-penguins 

penguin$bill_length_mm<-as.numeric(penguin$bill_length_mm)
penguin$bill_depth_mm<-as.numeric(penguin$bill_depth_mm)
penguin$flipper_length_mm<-as.numeric(penguin$flipper_length_mm)
penguin$body_mass_g<-as.numeric(penguin$body_mass_g)

penguin<-penguins%>% filter(sex!="")


#change the default "na.omit" to prevent models from being fitted to different datasets in case of missing values.
options(na.action = "na.fail")

#make the model
model1<-lm(bill_length_mm~bill_depth_mm+flipper_length_mm+body_mass_g,data=penguin)

#set up cluster for parallel processing
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)

#load MuMIn package and model1 onto cluster
clusterExport(cl, "model1")
clusterEvalQ(cl, library("MuMIn"))

combinations1<-parLapply(cl,model1,MuMIn::dredge)

#stop parallel
stopCluster(cl)
```

currently I'm getting the following error when I try to run the `parLapply` function: Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :
7 nodes produced errors; first error: no 'nobs' method is available

Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: The `MuMIn` package has a `pdredge()` function. This is a parallelized version of `dredge()`. Look at the [examples](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MuMIn/versions/1.47.5/topics/pdredge) to learn how to parallelize your task.

Comment: wow it's really as simple as `dredge(model1, cluster=cl)`. Guess I was overthinking it. Thanks!

Comment: just wanted to add in case it helps anyone later, I had to rename the cluster from cl to clu due to some error with the MuMIn package I don't pretend to understand that was causing R to not use the cluster. I also had to load the original dataframe ono the cluster like this: `clusterExport(clu, "penguin")`. Then it finally worked!